# How to map collections in proper way

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What is the best way for mapping collection of objects in NHibernate?
Now I am using bags, but maybe another approach can be more efficient?

Comment: What do you mean? Bags, sets, lists and maps are all "proper" ways. Use the one that matches your requirements.

Comment: You are not supposed to ask very vague questions here. As the previous comment, there are other "proper" ways depending on your requirements. If you want help from the forum, elaborate more in your questions and give examples or more information about it. Otherwise, your question doesn't help anyone else in the community.

Answer (score 0):

Before wore Bag and ClassMapping, something very similar to this:

```
        Bag(am => am.AlumnoMateriaId, map =>
            {
                map.Table("Calificacion");
                map.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                map.Key(k =>
                    {
                        k.Column("AlumnoId");
                        k.ForeignKey("FK_Calificacion_AlumnoMateria");
                    });
            }, rel => rel.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("AlumnoId")));
```

Now Use the NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes, and a class would look like:

using NHMA = NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes;

[NHMA.Class(Table = " Calificacion ")]

public class Calificacion
    {
        [NHMA.Id(0, Name = "id", TypeType = typeof(Int32), Column = "Id", Access =           "field")]
        [NHMA.Generator(1, Class = "native")]
        public Int32 id;

```
    public virtual Int32 Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [NHMA.ManyToOne(2, Name = "calificacion", Access = "field", Column = "CalificacionID",
    Class = "Calificacion", ClassType = typeof(Calificacion),
    ForeignKey = "FK_Calificacion_Alumno", NotNull = false)]
    private Calificacion calificaion;

    public virtual Calificacion Calificaion
    {
        get { return calificaion; }
        set { calificaion = value; }
    }



    [NHMA.Property(Name = "nombre", Access = "field", Column = "Nombre", Length = 50)]
    private string nombre;

    public virtual string Nombre
    {
        get { return nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }
```

}